# MUI Wrong prop passed to menu item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a react component that creates a list of elements and each element has a button that opens a menu the Issue is that the props passed to each menu are wrong. it always passes the props of last element in the list of elements.

```js
const TOC = (props) => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const map = useSelector((state) => state.app.mapContext);
  const layers = useSelector((state) => state.app.layers);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);


  const handleClick = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
  };


  const options = [
    {
        component: <ZoomInIcon />,
        key: "zoomIcon",
        cb: (lyrKey) => handleZoomClick(layers[lyrKey].vectorLayer),
        text: "Zoom",
    },
    {
        component: <DriveFileRenameOutlineIcon />,
        key: "renameLayer",
        cb: (lyrKey) => {
            console.log(lyrKey);
            dispatch(
                setDialog({
                    open: true,
                    title: `Change ${lyrKey} Layer name`,
                    child: <Rename old_name={lyrKey} />,
                })
            );
        },
        text: "Rename",
    },
  ];

return 
  <>
   {Object.keys(layers).map((lyrKey) => (
                <div className="toc__element" key={lyrKey}>
                    <label>
                        <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name={lyrKey}
                            checked={layers[lyrKey]?.show || false}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        {lyrKey}
                    </label>

                    <MoreVertIcon onClick={handleClick} />
                    <Menu
                        id="lock-menu"
                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                    >
                        {options.map((option) => (
                            <MenuItem
                                key={option.key + lyrKey}
                                onClick={(e) => {
                                    console.log(lyrKey);
                                    handleClose();
                                    option.cb(lyrKey);
                                }}
                            >
                                {option.text}
                                {option.component}
                            </MenuItem>
                        ))}
                    </Menu>
                </div>
            ))}

   </>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that There was 1 **anchorElement** for all menus.

What I did was separate the menu in other components and the issue was fixed.

```js
    export const IsolatedMenu = (props) => {
        const { lyrKey } = props;
        const map = useSelector((state) => state.app.mapContext);
        const layers = useSelector((state) => state.app.layers);
        const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
        const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    
        const handleClick = (event) => {
            setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
        };
        const handleClose = () => {
            setAnchorEl(null);
        };
    
        const handleZoomClick = (vl) => {
            map.getView().fit(vl.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
        };
    
        const options = [
            {
                component: <ZoomInIcon />,
                key: "zoomIcon",
                cb: (lyrKey) => handleZoomClick(layers[lyrKey].vectorLayer),
                text: "Zoom",
            },
            {
                component: <DriveFileRenameOutlineIcon />,
                key: "renameLayer",
                cb: (lyrKey) => {
                    console.log(lyrKey);
                    dispatch(
                        setDialog({
                            open: true,
                            title: `Change ${lyrKey} Layer name`,
                            child: <Rename old_name={lyrKey} />,
                        })
                    );
                },
                text: "Rename",
            },
        ];
    
        return (
            <>
                <MoreVertIcon onClick={handleClick} />
                <Menu
                    id="lock-menu"
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    open={open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    key={`menu-${lyrKey}`}
                    keepMounted
                >
                    {options.map((option) => (
                        <MenuItem
                            key={option.key}
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                console.log(lyrKey);
                                handleClose();
                                option.cb(lyrKey);
                            }}
                        >
                            {option.text}
                            {option.component}
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Menu>
            </>
        );
    };
```